# Олимпиада по информатике

Tags: python, python-3.x, олимпиада

Задача:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код не работает должным образом, как исправить?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
skill = {}
with open("input.txt") as file:
    n = int(file.readline())
    for i in range(n):  #составление словаря умений и подсчёт количества человек на каждое
        sk = int(file.readline())
        if sk in skill:
            skill[sk] += 1
        else:
            skill[sk] = 1
        if sk-1 > 0:
            if sk - 1 in skill:
                skill[sk-1] += 1
            else:
                skill[sk-1] = 1
        if sk + 1 in skill:
            skill[sk+1] += 1
        else:
            skill[sk+1] = 1
res = 0
for key in sorted(list(skill.keys())):
    if skill[key] > 0:
        res += 1
        skill[key] -= 1
        if key != 1:
            if key+2 in skill:
                skill[key+2] -= 1
        if key+1 in skill:
            skill[key+1] -= 1
with open("output.txt", "w") as out:
    out.writelines(str(res))
```

Comment: if sk in skill,keys()  Надо проверять входит ли в массив ключей. Вообще  у вас много лишнего. Не на до делать +1 и -1, просто добавьте единичку. Сортировка зачем? Просто подсчитайте ключи со значением 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ну у вас Питон и он умеет много гитик. Немного подробный код

```
with open("input.txt") as file:
    n = int(file.readline()) 
    lst=[] 
    for i in range(n): 
        lst.append(int(file.readline()))

res=len(list(dict.fromkeys(lst))) 

with open("output.txt", "w") as out:
    out.writelines(str(res))
```